# How to make a sum only query in a whole collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this collection

```
{ 
    "_id" : BinData(0, "JUw6VoBVdtqAQ2g7sn0sog=="), 
    "os_name" : "android" 
}
```

I want to retrieve in one aggregate query to count of documents with

```
os_android => count of documents where "os_name" = "android" 
os_ios => count of documents where "os_name" = "ios"
total => the total count of document
```

How can i do ?

I try this :

```
db.getCollection("myCollection").aggregate(
[
    {$group:{
      _id:{},
      by_os_ios:{$sum:{$cond:[{os_name:"ios"},NumberInt(1),NumberInt(0)]}},
      by_os_android:{$sum:{$cond:[{os_name:"android"},NumberInt(1),NumberInt(0)]}},
      total:{$sum:1}}
    },
    {$addFields:{
      "by_os.ios":"$by_os_ios",
      "by_os.android":"$by_os_android"}},
    {$project:{
      _id:0,
      by_os_ios:0,
      by_os_android:0}}
  ]
);
```

but it's not work :( what did I miss ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `$eq` in `$cond`, you can check condition using `{ $eq:["$field_name", "value to matched"] }`

```
db.getCollection("myCollection").aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {},
      by_os_ios: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$os_name", "ios"] }, 1, 0] } },
      by_os_android: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$os_name", "android"] }, 1, 0] } },
      total: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  ... // your other pipeline stages
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GL0O98vKutt)

---

Second possible way,

- `$group` to create array called root
- `$project` to get count of total documents using `$size`
- `$reduce` to iterate loop through root array and check condition if its ios then sum and if its android then sum using `$add` and merge with current object of value by `$mergeObjects`

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/APjSiijQHd5)